# Search list for number in range

Tags: python, list, search, range

How do you search for a number of a list in a range?
For example say l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] and the search range was 5 to 10. I would want to print each number 5-10 but am not sure how to write this code. I am new to programming!

Comment: Contrary to what was demonstrated below, Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Questions are expected to show *what you have tried so far*, and where exactly you're stuck. You should provide sample input, expected output, the actual output, and the full text of any errors or tracebacks you receive. Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), as well as how to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Okay thank you, I am new to this and appreciate the tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for item in items:
    if 5 <= item <= 10:
        print(item)
```

You might find [Python for Beginners](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/) useful.